# Visual Studio 2010 doesn't see namespace, but it exists

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, reference, namespaces

I have the solution, which has 5 projects. One of them: "Project.Core.Common" (.NEt Framework 3.5). I have a problem in them. When I try to compile, then I get error:

> Error 79  The type or namespace name 'Server' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'DllFile.Logging' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)   D:\Solution\Project.Core.Common

But this namespace `DllFile.Logging.Server` exists. I can see it by opening `DllFile.dll` in Object Browser.

Reference to `DllFile.dll` added in my project.

`DllFile.dll` has .NET FW 2.0.50727 runtime version.

I get 74 warnings about this `DllFile.dll`:

> Warning   4   The primary reference "DllFile.Logging.Server, Version=6.3.1.0,
>   Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved
>   because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly
>   "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which has a higher version "4.0.0.0"
>   than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current target
>   framework.    Project.Core.Common

But `DllFile.dll` doesn't use any dependencies to 4th framework. It written in 2.0 framework.

And the important thing: this project compiles without any errors on any computer except mine. I checked to compile it in the following environments:

```
VS 2010 (Windows XP SP3 x86)
VS 2010 (Windows 7 x86)
VS 2010 (Windows 7 x64)
VS 2013 (Windows 8.1 x64)
```

On every computer this project compiles fine. But on my computer (VS 2010 Windows XP SP3 x86) I get this error and warnings.

**What I tried to do:**

- I fully uninstalled VS 2010 and all its components and then install it again.
- I deleted the following folders:

> C:\Documents and Settings\User\Local Settings\Application
>   Data\assembly
>
> C:\Documents and Settings\User\Local Settings\Application Data\cache
>   (deleted just in case)
>
> C:\Documents and Settings\User\Local Settings\Application
>   Data\Microsoft\Team Foundation
>
> C:\Documents and Settings\User\Local Settings\Application
>   Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio
>
> C:\Documents and Settings\User\Local Settings\Application
>   Data\Microsoft\VSCommon
>
> C:\Documents and Settings\User\Local Settings\Application
>   Data\WebsiteCache\
>
> C:\Documents and Settings\User\VSWebCache
>
> C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application
>   Data\Microsoft\VSTAHost\SSIS_ScriptTask\9.0\ItemTemplatesCache
>
> C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\VSTAHost\SSIS_ScriptTask\9.0\ProjectTemplatesCache
>
> C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\VS\vs10sp1\SetupCache

- Deleted the following files:

> ```
> C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\vs000223.dat
> C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\1033\devenv.CTM
> C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\1033\ResourceCache.dll
> C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\VSA\9.0\1033\ResourceCache.dll
> C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\VSA\9.0\1033\vsaenv10.CTM
> C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\VSTAHost\SSIS_ScriptComponent\9.0\1033\ResourceCache.dll
> C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\VSTAHost\SSIS_ScriptTask\9.0\1033\ResourceCache.dll
> ```

- Cleared the following folder:

> ```
> C:\Documents and Settings\User\Local Settings\Temp
> ```

- I tried to clear VS cache too. I executed the following commands in cmd:

> ```
> cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE
> devenv /resetuserdata
> ```

But nothing helps.

What else can I to do to resolve my strange problem? (except reinstalling Windows)

**Edited:**

1. Changing the property 'Copy local' (true/false) for the reference 'DllFile.dll' not helps.
2. I tried to create the new empty project and add reference to this library 'DllFile.dll' and this error exists in the empty project too. So the problem is not in my real project.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Solution Explorer and select Show All Files. Then come to your project bin and expand DllFile.dll and see there is DllFile.dll.refresh file and if yes then delete and clean the solution and rebuild your projects should build successfully.

Comment: Thank's for the answer! But unfortunately my "bin" folder doesn't contain "DllFile.dll", because in reference properties the property 'Copy local' set to 'false'. And if I changed 'Copy local' to 'true', then nothing changes. My build error still exists.

Comment: Try removing all your .NET 2.0 framework dll's and replace them .NET framework 4.0 dll's that should eliminate the warnings you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old bug that exists even in Visual Studio 2019 (Community Edition).
The IDE do not update the project file of a project from which you're making a reference to another. But in a settings you're seeing as if the link is there. You should add the reference manually:

Write this to a project file (or can copy from another project where links is working fine):

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="...path...\YourProject.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

This fixes the problem.